# Toy virtual machine

Tags: c++, c++11

I am a web developer, trying to have fun with C++11, so any positive/negative feedback is very welcome.

This is a toy virtual machine with 3 registers and 3 commands:

**vm/vm.h**

```
#ifndef VM_H
#define VM_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "vtypes.h"

namespace violet
{

    class Vm
    {
        bool running;
        std::vector<u16> program;
        u16  regs[REGS_N];
        u16  pc;

    public:
        Vm(const std::vector<u16>);
        ~Vm();

        u16 fetch();
        int run();
        std::vector<u16> dump_regs() const;
        instruction decode(const unsigned int) const;
    };

}

#endif // VM_H
```

**vm/vm.cpp**

```
#include "vm.h"

namespace violet
{

    Vm::Vm(const std::vector<u16> program):
        running(false),
        program(program),
        pc(0)
    {

    }

    Vm::~Vm()
    {

    }


    u16 Vm::fetch()
    {
        return program.at(pc++);
    }

    int Vm::run()
    {
        running = true;
        instruction instr;

        if (program.empty()) return 1;
        while(running && pc < program.size())
        {
            instr = decode(fetch());
            switch(instr.code)
            {
                case i_halt:
                    running = false;
                    break;

                case i_loadi:
                    regs[instr.r0] = instr.imm;
                    break;

                case i_add:
                    regs[instr.r0] = regs[instr.r1] + regs[instr.r2];
                    break;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    std::vector<u16> Vm::dump_regs() const
    {
        return std::vector<u16>(std::begin(regs), std::end(regs));
    }

    instruction Vm::decode(const unsigned int opcode) const
    {
        instruction i;
        // Bits 15-12  (4bits) Instruction number
        // Bits 11-8   (4bits) Register number
        // Bits 7-0    (8bits) Immediate value

        i.code = (opcode & 0xF000) >> 12;
        i.r0   = (opcode & 0xF00)  >>  8;
        i.r1   = (opcode & 0xF0)   >>  4;
        i.r2   = (opcode & 0xF);
        i.imm  = (opcode & 0xFF);

        return i;
    }

}
```

**vm/vtypes.h**

```
#ifndef VTYPES_H
#define VTYPES_H

using u8  = unsigned char;    // At least 8-bits
using u16 = unsigned short;   // At least 16-bits   -  (Usually)

namespace violet
{

    const unsigned int REGS_N  {3};

    // Instructions
    const unsigned int i_halt  {0};
    const unsigned int i_loadi {0x1};
    const unsigned int i_add   {0x2};

    struct instruction
    {
        unsigned int code;
        unsigned int r0;
        unsigned int r1;
        unsigned int r2;
        int imm;
    };

}
#endif // VTYPES_H
```

**vm/main.cpp**

```
#include <vector>

#include "vm/vm.h"
#include "etc/utils.h"

using namespace violet;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int vm_res;
    const std::vector<u16> program = utils::load_program_file(argv[1]);
    Vm vm(program);
    vm_res = vm.run();

    for (auto r : vm.dump_regs())
    {
        std::cout << r << " ";
    }   std::cout << std::endl;

    return vm_res;
}
```

**asm/vlasm.h**

```
#ifndef VLASM_H
#define VLASM_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

#include "vm/vtypes.h"

namespace violet
{
    namespace vlasm
    {
        const char comment(';');
        const std::string i_halt("halt");
        const std::string i_loadi("loadi");
        const std::string i_add("add");

        const std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int>
        registers {
                {"r0", 0},
                {"r1", 1},
                {"r2", 2}
        };

        std::vector<unsigned int> parse_source(const std::vector<std::string>);
        std::vector<std::string> parse_line(const std::string);
        unsigned int parse_tokens(const std::vector<std::string>);
        unsigned int parse_reg(const std::string);
        void die(const char *);
    };

}

#endif // VLASM_H
```

**asm/vlasm.cpp**

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

#include "vlasm.h"

namespace violet
{
    namespace vlasm
    {
        std::vector<unsigned int>
        parse_source(const std::vector<std::string> source)
        {
            std::vector<unsigned int> program;

            for (auto line : source)
            {
                if (line[0] == comment) continue;
                std::vector<std::string> tokens = parse_line(line);
                program.push_back(parse_tokens(tokens));

            }

            return program;
        }

        std::vector<std::string>
        parse_line(const std::string line)
        {
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            std::vector<std::string> tokens {
                    std::istream_iterator<std::string>{iss},
                    std::istream_iterator<std::string>{}
            };

            return tokens;
        }

        unsigned int parse_tokens(const std::vector<std::string> tokens)
        {
            unsigned int opcode;

            if (tokens[0] == vlasm::i_halt)
            {
               opcode = violet::i_halt;
            }

            else if (tokens[0] == vlasm::i_loadi)
            {
                if (tokens.size() != 3) die("Invalid load operation");
                opcode = (violet::i_loadi      << 12) |
                         (parse_reg(tokens[1]) <<  8) |
                          std::stoi(tokens[2]) ;
            }

            else if (tokens[0] == vlasm::i_add)
            {
                if (tokens.size() != 4) die("Invalid addition operation");
                opcode = (violet::i_add << 12) |
                         (parse_reg(tokens[1]) << 8) |
                         (parse_reg(tokens[2]) << 4) |
                          parse_reg(tokens[3]);
            }

            else
            {
                die("Invalid instruction found");
            }


            return opcode;
        }

        unsigned int parse_reg(std::string reg_str)
        {
            std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int>::const_iterator
            r = registers.find(reg_str);

            if (r == registers.end()) die("Invalid register");
            return r->second;
        }

        void die(const char *message)
        {
            std::cerr << message << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**asm/main.cpp**

```
#include <vector>

#include <etc/utils.h>
#include "vlasm.h"

using namespace violet;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const std::vector<std::string> source = utils::load_source_file(argv[1]);
    const std::vector<unsigned int> program = vlasm::parse_source(source);

    return utils::write_program_file(argv[2], program);
}
```

**etc/utils.h**

```
#ifndef UTILS_H
#define UTILS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#include "vm/vtypes.h"

    namespace violet
    {

        namespace utils
        {
            std::vector<u16> load_program_file(const std::string);
            std::vector<std::string> load_source_file(const std::string);
            int write_program_file(const std::string, const std::vector<unsigned int>);
        }

    };

    #endif // UTILS_H
```

**etc/utils.cpp**

```
#include "utils.h"

namespace violet
{

    namespace utils
    {
        std::vector<u16>
        load_program_file(const std::string filename)
        {
            u16 instr;
            u8  bytes[2];
            std::vector<u16> result;

            std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);
            if (file.fail())
            {
                std::cerr << "Could not load program" << std::endl;
                return result;
            }

            while(file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(bytes), 2))
            {
                // Little endian
                instr = bytes[0] | bytes[1] << 8;
                result.push_back(instr);
            }

            return result;
        }

        std::vector<std::string>
        load_source_file(const std::string filename)
        {
            std::string line;
            std::vector<std::string> result;

            std::ifstream file(filename);
            if (file.fail())
            {
                std::cerr << "Could not load source" << std::endl;
                return result;
            }

            while(std::getline(file, line))
            {
                result.push_back(line);
            }

            return result;
        }

        int write_program_file(
                const std::string filename,
                const std::vector<unsigned int> program)
        {
            std::ofstream out(filename, std::ios::trunc | std::ios::binary);
            if (out.fail())
            {
                std::cerr << "Could not write program file" << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }

            for (auto i : program)
            {
                out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&i), sizeof(u16));
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

**Usage:**

```
$ violet /path/to/bin.s

$ vlasm /path/to/source.vl /path/to/bin.s
```

**Asm syntax:**

- `loadi [reg][val]` - load **immediate** value(`[val]`) to register(`[reg]`)
- `add [reg1][reg2][reg3]` - place the sum of `[reg2]` and `[reg3]` into `[reg1]`
- `halt` - stop the execution

**Example program**

```
; comments start with semicolon
loadi r0 100
loadi r1 200
add r2 r0 r1
; now r2 holds the value 300
halt
```

This program compiled to vm bytecode:

```
6410 c811 0122 0000
```

Answer (score 9):

A few notes to complete what @vnp already said:

- When you open several namespaces at once and close them at once, you better indent only once since the double indentation won't add to clarity but will produce "longer" lines. A future revision of the standard may introduce [nested namespaces definition](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4230.html), which makes clear that two namespaces opened and closed at once are generally considered a a single code unit.
- `if (out.fail())` is fine, but the idiomatic way to check whether errors occured while opening your file would be `if (not out)`. It's true for input fstreams as well as for output fstreams.
- If you're not planning to modify the parameter `filename` in `write_program_file` then you might as well take it by `const` reference instead of taking it by value. That also applies to `program` and most of the function parameters in your program (and in the wild).
- Using (`const`) references may also improve this loop:

  ```
  for (auto line : source) { /* ... */ }
  ```

  Here, every `line` is a *copy* of its equivalent in `source`. It doesn't seem that you alter `line` afterwise, therefore, you could make it a `const` reference instead:

  ```
  for (const auto& line : source) { /* ... */ }
  ```
- Try to declare your variables only when you need them. In `load_source_file`, you better declare `line` and `result` only after the error check, otherwise you will end up default-initializing them even when there is an error and your program will waste some time for construction *and* destruction. That may not really impact the speed of your program specifically, but on a more general note, try not to perform useless operations.
- Your destructor isn't doing anything in `Vm`, so you better follow the [rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and not implement it.
- This is something we shouldn't see anymore:

  ```
  using u8  = unsigned char;    // At least 8-bits
  using u16 = unsigned short;   // At least 16-bits   -  (Usually)
  ```

  C++11 includes the C99 header `<stdint.h>` (under the name `<cstdint>`) where typedefs such as `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` plus many more variants are defined. If you want a fixed-type integer, use `<cstdint>`, do not define it yourself.
- You could use typed `enum` to represent your instructions instead of several `const unsigned int` variables:

  ```
  // Instructions
  enum instructions: unsigned int
  {
      i_halt  = 0x0,
      i_loadi = 0x1,
      i_add   = 0x2
  };
  ```

  You can even use a [scoped enumeration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) (`enum class`) if you want more type safety.
- Instead of `u16 regs[REGS_N];`, you could use an `std::array<u16, REGS_N>`. [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a mere wrapper around a C array and its simplicity makes it generally zero-overhead. Moreover, it offers container-like goodies such as iterators. It's a more secure class for free! :)
- Why do you take a `const char*` parameter in the function `die` while you use `std::string` everywhere else in the project? You might as well be consistent and use an `std::string` here too.

Answer (score 6):

- I seriously doubt that `fetch` and `decode` have reason to be public. They constitute an intimate core of the machine; no sane processor exposes the innards of its pipeline. I understand that they could be instrumental in debugging the machine, which is a good rationale for a `debugger` class (`friend`ly to `Vm`). A public `step()` method would be nice.
- `dump_regs` is also a good candidate for `debugger`. In any case, `pc` must be part of the dump.
- Speaking of debugging, I would think of adding debug information (source file name and line numbers) to the program file.
- `load_program_file` expects little endiannes. However `write_program_file` uses a host endianness.

Comment: Personally, when I write yet another VM for fun, I prefer having fetch & decode et al as public, too. Not public to the end-consumer of the VM, but within the CPU component. That is, I would have something like a _pipeline_ or so, which then has fetch (I often use "tick"), and a _cpu_ which then has a _pipeline_ as a private member.